# Setting range to tinymce: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: javascript, tinymce

**Here's my code:**

```
range.setStart(range.startContainer, index);
range.setEnd(range.startContainer, parseInt(index) + parseInt((ed.line.text.split(' ')[2] || "").length));
```

**These are the values from the console:**

```
index: 1
eindex + (ed.line.text.split(' ')[2] || "").length: 2
ed.line.text.length: 2
```

And why do I get this error?:

> Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Comment: @Scree: range.startContainer is what kind of html element?

Comment: @Thariama That's in. It should be text, but it's HtmlParagraphElement. In chrome it's text. This issue happens in FF. Why does it get converted to HtmlParagraphElement? I never set it.

Comment: text nodes are getting handled differrent in different browsers!